# spark jobserver Missing settings.sh, exiting

Tags: shell, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I am trying to run `./server_start.sh` with **spark-jobserver**,
but it says

> "Missing /home/spark/spark-jobserver1.5.1/bin/settings.sh, exiting",

I also check the details in `./server_start.sh` from **github** where i found this(as the picture below):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqV4B.png)

It means the **setting.sh** should be exists but not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need spark binaries to be installed on you machine. And export SPARK_HOME. See local.sh.template for example.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I v already installed spark and started it ,also  iv edited the local.sh  [eg:]SPARK_HOME=/home/spark/spark5 .  i still dont know where can i get the setting.sh

Comment: i v configed it out ,it seems i must run deploy.sh first

Comment: I think deploy is to deploy the code in remote machine. Is that you are looking for?